# Unable to create order id in firebase cloud functions for razorpay [firebase_functions/internal] internal

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web, razorpay

I am using node.js for writing cloud functions in firebase but i am getting an error `[firebase_functions/internal] internal`.

My code in index.js:-

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const Razorpay = require('razorpay')
const instance = new Razorpay({
    key_id: 'my id',
    key_secret: 'my key'
})

exports.razorpayOrderId = functions.https.onCall(async(req, res) => {
    var options = {
      amount: 10000,
      currency: "INR",
    };
    try{
            instance.orders.create(options).then(order => console.log(order));
    }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
            res.status(403).send({error: 'error'});
    }
});
```

My code in flutter to trigger the function:-

```
HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable(
      'razorpayOrderId',
      options: HttpsCallableOptions(timeout: Duration(seconds: 5)),
    );
    try {
      final HttpsCallableResult result = await callable.call(
        <String, dynamic>{
          'message': 10000,
        },
      );
      print(result.data['response']);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `onCall()` function and not `onRequest()` so you must terminate the function by returning data/promise and not a response. `onCall()` takes 2 parameters usually named as `data` and `context` which are not same as `request` and `response` from Express:

```
exports.razorpayOrderId = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  var options = {
    amount: 10000,
    currency: "INR",
  };
  
  try {
    const order = await instance.orders.create(options)
    return {data: order}
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return { error: "Something went wrong" }
  }
});
```

You can read more about the difference in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

Comment: @DeepakLohmod try reinstalling node modules and deploy with this command: `firebase deploy --only functions --debug`. Then share the debug logs.

Comment: Is it safe to upload debug? like it contains my project id, email etc

Comment: @DeepakLohmod you can remove those details. Just don't remove any error like logs